# Neo4j toInt conversion on LOAD CSV

Tags: neo4j

During `LOAD CSV` I am converting a field to integer with `toInt`, and while I do not recieve any error (and the data load), the property is still being considered a string.

Below is my code that I am running to populate the database.  I have a small toy dataset that you can reference below.

```
// Import the HS Cluster nodes
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11f7-aEN-OURzzPY97Cm8vWZN1lNqYpSmCocNkzAoQe8/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv" as row
WITH row
MERGE (s:Student {sid:row.id});


// Import the contacts
// THIS IS THE QUERY THAT I AM USING toINT
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11f7-aEN-OURzzPY97Cm8vWZN1lNqYpSmCocNkzAoQe8/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv" as row
WITH row
MERGE (c:Contact {cid:row.cid, seqnum: toInt(row.seqnum)} );


// Connect the next contacts together
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11f7-aEN-OURzzPY97Cm8vWZN1lNqYpSmCocNkzAoQe8/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv" as row
WITH row
WHERE row.nextcid <> 'NA'
MERGE (c:Contact {cid:row.cid})
MERGE (n:Contact {cid:row.nextcid})
MERGE (c)-[:NEXT]->(n);
```

But when I get to the point of referencing the property for in another query

```
// I expected this to work
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11f7-aEN-OURzzPY97Cm8vWZN1lNqYpSmCocNkzAoQe8/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv" as row
WITH row
WHERE row.seqnum = 1
MERGE (c:Contact {cid:row.cid})
MERGE (s:Student {sid:row.id})
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_CONTACT]->(c);
```

But this yields `(no changes, no rows)`

However, when I reference `seqnum` as a string, it works as expected

```
// but have to reference seqnum as a string 
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11f7-aEN-OURzzPY97Cm8vWZN1lNqYpSmCocNkzAoQe8/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv" as row
WITH row
WHERE row.seqnum = '1'
MERGE (c:Contact {cid:row.cid})
MERGE (s:Student {sid:row.id})
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_CONTACT]->(c);
```

What am I missing?

For reference, I am running community edition of neo4j 2.3.1, and am on OSX 10.9.5.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 'expected it to work' part you filter the property in your CSV file, not on the node:

```
WHERE row.seqnum = 1 // this is still a string from your CSV file
```

You converted the `seqnum` property on the node, the CSV file stays the same.

Try to `MATCH` a `Contact` node to see if the value was converted to int for the node:

```
MATCH (c:Contact {cid: 'some_id_here', seqnum: 1} )
RETURN c
```

Comment: I knew it was something that I was over-looking.  Thanks